# How I use helpers in ActionView instance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How I use helper methods in an ActionView instance?

I create an ActiveView object in Worker to render a layout in background.
I write a helper in helpers directory, but I can't use in layout rendered by my worker:

In app/workers/worker.rb:

```
av = ActionView::Base.new
av.view_paths = ActionController::Base.view_paths
# ...
av.render :template => "...", layout => "layouts/my_layout"
```

In app/helpers/my_helper.rb:

```
module MyHelper
    def my_tag(param)
        # do something
    end
end
```

In app/views/layouts/my_layout.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <%= my_tag "application" %>
    </head>
    <body>...</body>
</html>
```

It's this throw error in foreman:

```
ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `my_tag' for #<ActionView::Base:0xc3da390>
```

System:

ruby -v: `ruby 1.9.3p448`,
rails -v: `Rails 3.2.11`

Comment: Have you tried adding `av.extend MyHelper`?

Comment: Have you tried including them in your worker? `helper MyHelper` or `include MyHelper`?

Comment: @d_ethier, I tried, i isn't work. Worker only creates the ActionView object, is `av` object who needs the helper method.

Comment: @BroiSatse this is a solution, Thank you!